# customStyles not being read

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

```
import React from 'react'

const CustomButton = ({ type, title, customStyles, handleClick }) => { 
  return (
    <button
        className={'px-2 py-1.2 flex-1 rounded-md ${customStyles}'}
    >
        {title}
    </button>
  )
}

export default CustomButton
```

The customStyles keeps saying it's declared but not being read. The customStyles is not being applied to the site, but everything else is. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The issue is with how you are using template literals in the `className` attribute.
- Use backticks ``` (``) ``` instead of single quotes `('')` around the whole string.
- like this

```
className={`px-2 py-1.2 flex-1 rounded-md ${customStyles}`}
```

Comment: You could just vote up my solution instead of same solution. Anyway, we both got the same solution, that's too kind of vote up :)

Comment: I tried to vote up on both but I don't have enough rates or something. I just made this account

Comment: @Anshu I have voted you. Good Luck!

Comment: @ Anshu, i didn't notice your answer i guess we've answered on same time i counldn't post my answer due to the 30 min rule.

Comment: @Anshu It was not intentional! voted up+!!!

Comment: @YashashriPawar No problem, to avoid this issue, I usually re-check solutions before posting. It was 8 min difference. Anyway, that's not the point.

Comment: @Anshu i'm sure there wasn't any answers posted when i started! i simply got late because i was prohibited to post within 30 min! so i could'nt notice your answer there. will be careful posting next time!

Answer (score 3):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are enclosed by the back-tick instead of single or double quotes.

use `` className={`px-2 py-1.2 flex-1 rounded-md ${customStyles}`} ``

Comment: @Rob I'm glad I could help!